# How to transmit the signal of N switches with a CAN network

Tags: microcontroller, can

I currently use N inputs from my microcontroller to read the N signal switches. But when the number of switches is too large, this becomes unfeasible. With this I started to study a CAN network to transmit using only two wires. But I do not know how to do this in the case of switches, whether to use a CAN module for all or not.

How do I transmit the signal of N switches with a CAN network?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fce4yE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If the switches are physically near the microcontroller, it is not uncommon to use a shift register (74hc165) to expand the number of inputs. You can also use scanned switch matrix topologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CAN works by sending frames.  Data frames can contain up to 8 bytes of arbitrary data, and have either a 11 bit or 29 bit ID.

In a very simple system, you could assign one ID to indicate the state of each block of 64 switches.  One processor would then monitor 64 switches at a time, and transmit the associated CAN frame whenever any of the switch inputs changed.

You don't need to use all 8 data bytes in every frame.  If 64 inputs is too much to handle per processor, then you could just send 4 bytes in each frame, and therefore monitor 32 switches in a block.  ID 0 could be switches 0-31, ID 2 switches 32-63, etc.